# Set UIBarButtonItem Text to Size According to Length of Text

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I'm programmatically changing the text of a UIBarButtonItem.  In most cases, it works out fine but in some cases, it is extremely long and overtakes the title bar.

I'm looking for a way to set the font-size to change to fit within a certain boundary so it doesn't overtake the title.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm away from a compiler to test this but you could try something like:

```
var size = 18 - (btn.titleLabel?.text.characters.count / 3)
btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica" , size: size )
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to change the font size of a `UIBarButtomItem` is by using a custom view:

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 44))
label.text = "Hello world!"
label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: UIFont.smallSystemFontSize)

let barButton1 = UIBarButtonItem()
barButton1.customView = label
...
```

That way, you can control the font size on the `UILabel` and make it smaller when you need to.